# How to select rows of an array, for which all cells pass a defined logical test?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to select rows of an array, for which all cells pass a defined logical test.

For instance, considering the following array A:

```
A = np.array([[1,3,5,7,9,10],[2,4,6,8,11,15],[13,15,0,7,3,1]])
```

And the logical conditions:

```
(A>1) & (A<15)
```

I would like to select the rows, where all cells fulfill the logical conditions, and thus in this example I would expect selecting:

```
[1,3,5,7,9,10]
```

I have tried the following command:

```
A_filtered = A[(A>1) & (A<15)]
```

but, even though `(A>1) & (A<15)` is a 3x6 boolean array, the result `A_filtered` is in fact a list of the 13 values of the array that pass the logical test.

Which commands should I use to select the rows, whose all cells pass the logical conditions?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be solved with a list comprehension, but perhaps also possible directly in numpy.

```py
[x for x in A if all(x >= 1) and all(x < 15)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I enclosed the command in np.array() to get an array instead of a list as output:
np.array([x for x in A if all(x >= 1) and all(x < 15)])